# How to include BengaliAnalyzer in SOLR

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I want to include BengaliAnalyzer in solr.

How to include BengaliAnalyzer in solr managed-schema.xml? I have to search both Bengali and English.

I am using Solrj and Solr 7.6.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use either `BengaliNormalizationFilterFactory` or `BengaliStemFilterFactory` in your Solr schema easily.

Example of the definition in your *schema* file (schema.xml or managed-schema) could be something like this:

```
<fieldType name="text_bn" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer> 
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/> 
        <filter class="solr.BengaliNormalizationFilterFactory"/> 
        <filter class="solr.BengaliStemFilterFactory"/>       
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Example of normalisation - `মানুষ` -> `মানুস` and example of applying stemming - `সমস্ত` -> `সমস্`

If you want to search both languages, I would recommend to create this field type and also uses the default `text_en` field type which is available in Solr.

Comment: Thanks. I will inform you after trying.